# SQL Server 2008 Query to Delete All Rows Where Values Are Not Found in 3 Other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am working on a SQL Server 2008 database where all items that can be used in the database are stored in table A with a key value of ItemNum. Table B and Table C use ItemNum as a key value and are where the items from table A are actually used. Table A contains many duplicates that aren't used in Table B and Table C. I need to delete all ItemNum from Table A that are not used in tables B or table C.

Right now I have the following two queries using `Select` statements (which will eventually be switched to `Delete` statements) which I am not sure are working correctly, and I want to create the most efficient query possible.

```
    USE Database
    GO

    SELECT ItemNum 
    FROM B
    WHERE EXISTS 
        (SELECT ItemNum FROM A WHERE A.ItemNum = B.ItemNum)

    USE Database
    GO

    SELECT ItemNum 
    FROM C
    WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT ItemNum FROM A WHERE A.ItemNum = C.ItemNum)
```

Comment: where ... not in (select x from x) and ... not in (...) and .... not in (...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple DELETE JOIN;

```
DELETE A FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.itemnum = B.itemnum
LEFT JOIN C ON A.itemnum = C.itemnum
WHERE b.itemnum IS NULL
  AND c.itemnum IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea351/1).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?:

```
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE ItemNum NOT IN(SELECT ItemNum FROM TableB) and ItemNum NOT IN(SELECT ItemNum FROM TableC)
```

Comment: This also works, but using Delete Join is just cleaner for my purposes. Thanks for your help though